# How to limit a formula in excel upto a particular row then again start the formula from the next column?

Tags: excel

I have to use a particular formula till like the 10th row then stop it there and then start fresh again from the 11th row.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple example. The following formula will sum from `A1` to `A5`. When it reach to `A6` then it will start summing again from `A1` to `A5`.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:" &"A"&IF(MOD(ROW(),5)=0,5,MOD(ROW(),5))))
```